# How do I playout rtmp stream to SDI (Decklink Studio 4K) using FFMPEG command?we are using Windows 7 operating system

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, sdi, sd-card, blackmagic

ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://server/live/streamname \
-c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt uyvy422 -vf scale=720x576 \
-c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 \
-f nut - | /bmd/bmdplay -C 0 -m 2 -f pipe:0

**Kindly share the exact command to take this rtmp stream to Decklink Studio 4K card(SDI).**

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#decklink-1) say,

> you need the Blackmagic DeckLink SDK and you need to configure with
>   the appropriate --extra-cflags and --extra-ldflags. On Windows, you
>   need to run the IDL files through widl

If so, run

```
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://server/live/streamname -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt uyvy422 -vf scale=720x576 -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -f decklink "Device"
```

where `Device` is to replaced with the name of 'Decklink Studio 4K' as indicated by `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i nullsrc -f decklink -list_devices 1 dummy`